# Create new Linked Work Item in TFS2010 - can I set default values?

Tags: tfs-workitem

When we create a new linked work item `New Linked Work Item...` or `Ctrl+Shift+L`, is there a way to copy the title and other data from the original work item ?

Here's the scenario: I have a custom Work Item Type called `Code Review` which needs to be created for every task. Not every one, but most ones. Sure, one could open both work items and copy, but I'm trying to make it as simple as possible.

What I really want to do is a VS2010 extension with a button to create the code review work items. But before I resort to that, I wanted to know if there is a simpler (and quicker) way to create new linked work items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the 'Create copy of work item..' & set the WI-type to what you need, all matching fields should get copied.

Comment: I think they get the relationship 'related'. I'm not at the office right now to check it out - so I might be wrong

Comment: When you do that, a link with link type 'related' is created between both work items

Comment: And I'm supposed I can't change this behavior? I wanted to create another link type

Comment: I'm creating an add-in, but will mark this as answer because it was the closest it could get.